# how to fix "Successfully Added" message when the form aren't select all checkbox using php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need helps, please. The problem is the alert messages of successfully added  not show when i don't select all checkbox on the form. I want success message show up when i select one or two checkbox. the "successfully added" message show only when i select all of them. Am i use use wrong condition?

**the picture like this.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stHeJ.png)

**here are my source code**

*equipment.php*

```
<!-- add modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="equipmentAdd">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Equipment</h4>
          </div>

          <form class="form-horizontal" action="php_action/equipment_create.php" method="POST" id="createEquipmentForm">

          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="messages"></div>
              <div class="form-group"> <!--/here teh addclass has-error will appear -->
                <label for="number" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                  <select class="form-control" id="number" name="number">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>

                        <?php endwhile;?>

                    </select>
                <!-- here the text will apper  -->
                </div>
              </div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Please Select some Equipments</strong></h3>
                </div>

                    <br>

                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 0px;"><strong><u><font color="red">Living Room</font></u></strong></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 35px;">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="tv" value="Tv" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/tv-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">TVs</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 35px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="phone" value="Phone" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/phone-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">Phone</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 35px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="fan" value="Fan" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/fan-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">Fan</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 35px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="mirror" value="Mirror" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/mirror-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">Mirrors</span>
                                </label>    
                            </div><!-- form group -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 26px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="wifi" value="Wi-Fi" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/wifi-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">Wi-Fi</span>
                                </label>                       
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 7px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="bookshelf" value="BookShelf" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/bookshelf-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">BookShelf</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 30px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="sofa" value="Sofa" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/sofa-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">Sofa</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 35px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="clock" value="Clock" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                        <img src="img/equipments/clock-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">Clock</span>
                                </label>    
                            </div><!-- form group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

*equipment_create.php*

```
<?php include 'db_connect.php';
if ($_POST) {

    $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    /*$checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['equipment']);*/


    $tv = $_POST['tv'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $fan = $_POST['fan'];
    $mirror = $_POST['mirror'];
    $wifi = $_POST['wifi'];
    $bookshelf = $_POST['bookshelf'];
    $sofa = $_POST['sofa'];
    $clock = $_POST['clock'];

    //submit a checkbox for a row
    if ($number && $tv && $comment) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment', '$tv')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if ($number && $phone && $comment ) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment', '$phone')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if ($number && $comment && $fan) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment', '$fan')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if ($number && $comment && $mirror) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment','$mirror')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if ($number && $comment && $wifi) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment','$wifi')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if ($number && $comment && $bookshelf) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment','$bookshelf')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if ($number && $comment && $sofa) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment','$sofa')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if ($number && $comment && $clock) {
       $sql="INSERT INTO equipment (rNumber, comment, equipment) VALUES ('$number', '$comment',' $clock')";     
       $query = $connect->query($sql);
    }

    if($query === TRUE) {           
        $validator['success'] = true;
        $validator['messages'] = "Successfully Added";      
    } else {        
        $validator['success'] = false;
        $validator['messages'] = "Error while adding the equipment information";
    }

    // close the database connection
    $connect->close();

    echo json_encode($validator);
```

}

Note: one checkbox is insert a row. here is the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTbr4.png)

*equipment.js*

```
$("#addEquipmentModalBtn").on('click', function() {
    // reset the form 
    $("#createEquipmentForm")[0].reset();
    // remove the error 
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    // empty the message div
    $(".messages").html("");
    // submit form
    $("#createEquipmentForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        $(".text-danger").remove();
        var form = $(this);

        // validation
        var number = $("#number").val();

        if(number == "") {
            $("#number").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            $("#number").after('<p class="text-danger">The Room Number field is required</p>');
        } else {
            $("#number").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $("#number").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');                
        }

        if (number) {
            //submit the form to server
            $.ajax({
                url : form.attr('action'),
                type : form.attr('method'),
                data : form.serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success:function(response) {

                    // remove the error 
                    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                    if(response.success == true) {
                        $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');

                        // reset the form
                        $("#createEquipmentForm")[0].reset();       

                        // reload the datatables
                        manageEquipmentTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                        // this function is built in function of datatables;

                    } else {
                        $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');
                    }  // /else
                } // success  
            }); // ajax subit               
        }//if


        return false;
    }); // /submit form for create member
}); // /add modal
```

});//

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the PHP part as:

```php
$tv = isset($_POST['tv'])?$_POST['tv']:0;
$phone = isset($_POST['phone'])?$_POST['phone']:0;
$fan = isset($_POST['fan'])?$_POST['fan']:0;
```

and so on.